# PostgreSQL error while searching for empty string using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

This code outputs expected results on PGAdmin

```
select * from reports where manifesto_id = ' ' order by report_id
```

but when i run it using PHP pg_query_params like this

```
pg_query_params($connection,'select * from reports where manifesto_id = $1 order by report_id',array(' '));
```

i get the error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' order by report_id'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

i have tried using where manifesto_id is Null, but obviously

```
' ' != Null
```

so i don't get the desired results. Any help?

Comment: Try using double quotes in the query.. I think it's putting in literally `' '` which is breaking your query

Comment: I believe it's breaking the query because you are using single quotation marks `'` within single quotation marks, try changing the query string to `"select * from reports where manifesto_id = $1 order by report_id"`

Comment: Why would the ID be an empty string with a length of 1? Is it supposed to be `""`? In which case you could try `where char_length(manifesto_id) = 0`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but non has worked for now @brianforan, i know i would have made it an empty string with length zero but the DB is already in use

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work @Rimble

Comment: What if you don't use a parameter? If you're just checking for " " I don't really see a reason to use a parameter, it's not user based

Comment: It worked thanks a lot@brianforan